# Why is rand() not so random after fork?

Tags: c, random, fork

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int i =10;
    /* initialize random seed:  */
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(i--){
        if(fork()==0){
            /* initialize random seed here does not make a difference:
            srand(time(NULL));
             */
            printf("%d : %d\n",i,rand());
            return;
        }
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Prints the same (different on each run) number 10 times - expected ?
I have a more complicated piece of code where each forked process runs in turn - no difference

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The outputs *must* be the same. If two processes each seed the random number with the same seed and each call `rand` once, they *must* get the same result. That's the whole point of having a seed. All of your processes call `srand` with the same seed (because you only call `srand` once) and they all call `rand` once, so they *must* get the same result.

Uncommenting the `srand` won't make a difference because unless the number of seconds has changed, they will still give the same seed. You could do:

```
srand(time(NULL) ^ (getpid()<<16));
```

Comment: Would you mind briefly explaining what is going on under the hood `^ (getpid()<<16)` being done?

Comment: The `time(NULL)` ensures you get a different value every second. The `(getpid()<<16)` increases the odds you'll get a different value for each process because process IDs aren't typically re-used that quickly.

Comment: I got that part sir I mean why is XOR operation used instead of & or |? I'm at that(math) part.

Comment: @snr XOR ensures that any change on either side changes the result. 8&1 is the same as 8&2, so & is out. 9|1 is the same as 9|9, so | is out.

Answer (score 5):

The `rand()` function is a *pseudo-random* number generator. This means that the *sequence* of numbers generated is deterministic, depending only upon the seed provided.

Because you are forking the same process 10 times, the state of the random number generator is the same for each child. The next time you call `rand()` you will get the same value.

By calling `srand(time(NULL))` inside the child process, you are *potentially* helping but the granularity of `time()` is only 1 second, so all your children probably start inside the same second. Seeding with the same value generates the same pseudo-random sequence.

You could try seeding with a value that depends on the child number:

```
srand(time(NULL) - i*2);
```

(I used `i*2` in the event that `time()` advances by 1 second during the fork loop.)

Comment: Overall a good idea but it'd be wise to incorporate the child number in a much more significant fashion. `time(NULL) + 100 * i` or something similar to ensure a one or two second difference won't influence the seed.

Comment: Good point, I like David Schwartz's idea of using the child pid.

Comment: Yeah, I really liked how he mixed it in _high_, too, but with applications that `clone(2)` instead of `fork(2)` it'd be possible for them all to have the same `pid` but different values for `i`. Slight nuance difference that might never matter to anyone...

Comment: The nice thing with the pid is that the results are never the same even if ones runs it very fast

Answer (score 5):

If your code is running fast enough, `srand()` might be seeded with the exact same time for each fork. `time()` only changes every second.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that even adding `srand(time(NULL));` (the line inside the `if` block that you have commented) inside the loop isn't making a difference is because modern computers can execute that whole block extremely fast, and `time` counts in seconds. From the man pages:

> time()  returns  the  time  as  the  number of seconds since the Epoch...

If you add a `sleep(1);` after the `if` statement in the `while` loop and uncomment the `srand` call, the results will be different, since `time` would now return a different value because a second has elapsed.

It would however be more appropriate to use a different seed value, rather than waiting. Something like `i` would be a good idea since it'll be unique for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're not reseeding when you make a child process. The state of the random number generator is exactly the same.

Even if you seed again in your child, you're seeding with the time with a +/- 1 second granularity. When you fork, it all happens in less than a second.

Try seeding it with something different and more random.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because all programs are seeded with the same value (outside that while loop). You should seed again once you've forked the new program or both will produce the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This solve the problem:

```
srand48((long int)time(NULL));
i= (lrand48()/rand()+1) % 123
```

I havent tested with fork, but inside a for calling 100 times it works.

seed with the pid number. It's a little but difficult to solve problem.

This was in some page: "this worked srand(time(0)+getpid()); but I had to call this within the case 0 i.e child process".

Comment: I do not understand your english