# C, rand function doesn't work properly with sleep() function

Tags: c, random, sleep

First of all, I know there is a lot of questions about rand() function but I think this is different.

Actually rand() function always works properly when I didn't combine with sleep() function. I tried it. But when I combine rand() function with sleep() like this "sleep(rand() %5)", sometimes it product random time for all child processes, as I expected, but sometimes works well for first 4-5 children, after that it products 0 for all remaining child processes. So other child processes don't sleep. And sometimes it always products 0 for all child processes.

BTW, I'm coding on Ubuntu 64bit.

About my code:
I want to fork 8 children from parent process and print their pid numbers one by one. But I should use sleep function after creating a child. Sleeping time should be random. I used time() function as a seed and try to use rand function but it doesn't work properly with sleep function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void childs();
void parent();


int id;
int i;
int pidID[9];
int fd[2];
char buff[100];
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t child;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        pipe(fd);

        child = fork();
        wait(NULL);
        if(child){
            parent();
            continue;
        }else if(child == 0){
            childs();
            break;
        }else{
            perror("State\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if(child ==0){
    printf("I am a child pid: %d, ppid: %d pidno: %d\n", getpid(), getppid(),pidID[i+1]);
    }else{
    printf("I am a parent pid: %d, ppid: %d pidno: %d\n", getpid(), getppid(),pidID[0]);
    }

}


void childs(){
id = getpid();
pidID[i + 1] = id;
char swap[50];
sprintf(swap, "%d" ,id);
write(fd[1], swap, 10);
srand(time(NULL));
int randomTime = rand() %5;
printf("Random time: %d\n",randomTime);
sleep(randomTime);
}



void parent(){
pidID[0] = getpid();
read(fd[0], buff , 10);
printf("Buff: %s\n", buff);
}
```

Comment: Define what you mean with "works well" and what you mean with "becomes `0` ...".

Comment: I mean sometimes rand() products random numbers, as I expected. But sometimes it products only 0. I will edit question now.

Comment: Format&indent your code properly. And non-prototype function declarators are deprecated by the standard. Don't use them.

Comment: Seeding the random number generator from the current time is never correct. The best you can say for it is that occasionally it is not harmful.

Comment: @rici what should I use instead of time as a seed? What would you suggest?

Comment: On unix, /dev/rand or /dev/urand. Other OSs have equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `srand` with `time(NULL)` in each child process, all children launched in the same second will seed with the same value.

Of course, with the `sleep` and `wait` involved, if the children `sleep` for a second, they'll seed with a new value, so things would mostly work out if you were always sleeping.

But `rand() % 5` produces values between 0 and 4; the first time a given `time` seed would cause the first `rand()` output to be a multiple of five, you sleep for 0 seconds, the child exits almost immediately, and the loop forks a new child, all in the space of a few milliseconds at most. And it will keep doing this for a solid second (or more) until the `time` reseed changes the first output of `rand` to a value which isn't a multiple of five.

If you want to fix this, the simplest (if still silly) approach would be to change:

```
int randomTime = rand() %5;
```

to:

```
int randomTime = rand() %5 + 1; // Range 1-5, or use rand() % 4 + 1 for 1-4
```

so you never have a sleep of less than a second, and you never enter the pathological case of constantly reseeding with the same time that produces the same zero second sleep over and over.

Alternatively, if zero second sleeps must be a possibility, use a more fine-grained `time` function to get a more rapidly varying seed. For example, on a POSIX system, you might instead use [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) which should vary much more rapidly:

```
struct timespec tm;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tm);
// xor-ing with tv_nsec >> 31 to ensure even low precision clocks vary
// the low 32 bits
srand((unsigned)(tm.tv_sec ^ tm.tv_nsec ^ (tm.tv_nsec >> 31)));
```

and you can continue to use `rand() % 5` because the time between `srand`s should be long enough to have changed a few values in `tv_nsec` and get a different seed value.

Comment: It make sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a suggestion for seeding each child differently - mix in the pid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8623196/12711

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Good point. Though technically, since each child exits before the next launches, there is no guarantee that a weird system wouldn't just reissue the same PID over and over (in practice, every system I've ever seen cycles so it doesn't reissue until all unused PIDs have been issued once, but I don't think that's mandatory, so pathological systems could mess you up). If you had many children running simultaneously, that would work fine no matter what though.

Comment: You could mix in `i` from the loop that forks the children.