# Processes does not seem to decrement semaphore

Tags: c, process, semaphore

I've got a problem with my c program.
*I already wrote a subject about the same program here (I had problems with fork) : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132029/wrong-data-output-when-forking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132029/wrong-data-output-when-forking_)*

I'm simulating an F1 practice. Whith fork now, I've got some irrelevant data (1/3 of cars have a wrong time (0min0s0ms).
I think it's a problem of concurrency so I tried to *implements a semaphore*.
The purpose of that is to only allow 1 process at a time to write in the Shared Memory.

But now, I have all the output data that are wrong

For instance:

- Pilote numbers are incorrect for most (a lot have n°0).
- They all have unrealistic best times (0min 0sec 0ms).

One thing I noticed is that if I remove the *sem operation* that increase the semaphore of 1 *(sem + 1)*, **no process is blocked before writing in the Shared Memory** but they should because the semaphore is never incremented *(it's only still decrementing)*.

Here's the programm that "make the race":

```
/* /!\ COMPILER AVEC -lm && -lpthread /!\ */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <wait.h>

#include "CourseF1.h"
#include "ResultCourse.h"

#define MAX_PILOTES 22
#define MAX_TOURS 44

int semid;

float ranf() { // PRNG for floats [0, 1].
    float r = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    return r;
}

/**
*
* method based on Box-Muller transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform
*
**/
float randGaussien(float m, float s) { /* median m, standard deviation s */
    float x1, x2, w, y1, result;
    float y2;
    int use_last = 0;

    if (use_last) /* use value of last call */
    {
        y1 = y2;
        use_last = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        do {
            x1 = 2.0 * ranf() - 1.0;
            x2 = 2.0 * ranf() - 1.0;
            w = x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
        } while ( w >= 1.0 );

        w = sqrt( (-2.0 * log( w ) ) / w );
        y1 = x1 * w;
        y2 = x2 * w;
        use_last = 1;
    }

    result = ( m + y1 * s );
    if (result < 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return result;
}


int genTime(const int min, const int max) {
    return ((rand() % (max-min + 1)) + min); // Generate a random number between min and max
}

int genRaceEvents(const int max) { // Decide about race events
    return rand() % max; // Generate a number between 0 and max - 1
}

int compareBest(const void *p1, const void *p2) { // Compare the best times
    const struct Pilote *elem1 = p1;
    const struct Pilote *elem2 = p2;

    if (elem1->best < elem2->best) return -1;
    if (elem1->best > elem2->best) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int compareTot(const void *p1, const void *p2) { // Compare the total times
    const struct Pilote *elem1 = p1;
    const struct Pilote *elem2 = p2;

    if (elem1->totalTime < elem2->totalTime) return -1;
    if (elem1->totalTime > elem2->totalTime) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void fillTab(struct Pilote tabToFill[], struct Pilote tabFiller[], const int start, const int stop) {
    for (int i = start; i < stop; i++) {
        tabToFill[i] = tabFiller[i];
    }
}

int run(Pilote *p, char* name) {
    struct sembuf sem_op; // sembuf struct for semaphore operations

    sem_op.sem_num = 0;
    sem_op.sem_op = -1; // sem - 1
    sem_op.sem_flg = 0;

    if (semop(semid, &sem_op, 1) == -1) { // sem operation
        perror("Error when decrementing semaphore");
    }

    /* Instantiation of Pilote struct values */
    p->s1 = 3 * 60 * 3600 + 1;
    p->bestS1 = 3 * 60 * 3600 + 1;
    p->s2 = 3 * 60 * 3600 + 1;
    p->bestS2 = 3 * 60 * 3600 + 1;
    p->s3 =  3 * 60 * 3600 + 1;
    p->bestS3 = 3 * 60 * 3600 + 1;
    p->best =  3 * 60 * 3600 + 1;
    p->totalTime = 0;
    p->isPit = 0;
    p->hasGivenUp = 0;
    p->hasGivenUpDuringRace = 0;
    p->numberOfPits = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOURS; i++) { // For every lap

        p->isPit = 0; // At first he doesn't pit

        if (!(p->hasGivenUp)) { // If the pilote didn't give up

            int givingUpEvent = genRaceEvents(500); // Generate a number between 0 and 499

            if (givingUpEvent == 14 && strcmp(name, "Race") == 0) { // If the pilote has given up (during race)
                p->best = 3 * 60 * 3600;
                p->hasGivenUpDuringRace = 1;
                return 0; // Stop le pilote
            }

            else if (givingUpEvent == 14) { // If the pilote has given up (but not during race)
                p->best = 3 * 60 * 3600 + 3;
                p->hasGivenUp = 1;
                return 0; // Stop the pilote
            }
        }

        if (p->numberOfPits < 2) { // Max 2 stops
            p->isPit = genRaceEvents(250); // Generate a number between 0 and 249

            if (p->isPit) {
                p->numberOfPits++;
                if ((strcmp(name, "Practices") == 0)|| (strcmp(name, "Qualifs") == 0)) continue; // Next iteration
            }

        }

        // We do a lap
        int S1 = 0.275 * (103000 + randGaussien(5000, 2000)); // Portion of circuit * Gauss curve (min time + fun(median, standard deviation))
        int S2 = 0.459 * (103000 + randGaussien(5000, 2000));
        int S3 = 0.266 * (103000 + randGaussien(5000, 2000));

        if ((strcmp(name, "Race") == 0) && (p->isPit)) { // If we are during race and the pilote pit
            S1 += genTime(20 * 3600, 25 * 3600); // We add between 20 and 25sec at Sector 1
        }

        p->s1 = S1; // Notify time of S1
        p->s2 = S2; // Notify time of S2
        p->s3 = S3; // etc...

        int lap = S1 + S2 + S3;

        if (p->bestS1 > S1) p->bestS1 = S1; // If it's its best S1, we modify the best S1
        if (p->bestS2 > S2) p->bestS2 = S2; // etc
        if (p->bestS3 > S3) p->bestS3 = S3; // etc

        if (p->best > lap) p->best = lap; // If it's its best lap time, we modify the best lap time, 

        if ((strcmp(name, "Race") == 0)) {
            p->totalTime += lap; // add the lap time to the total race time
        }

    } // End of for loop

    sem_op.sem_num = 0;
    sem_op.sem_op = 1; // sem + 1
    sem_op.sem_flg = 0;
    if (semop(semid, &sem_op, 1) == -1) { // sem operation
        perror("Error when incrementing semaphore");
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    //srand (time(NULL)); // Useful for random number generation

    printf("========================================\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        printf("Random: %d\n", genRaceEvents(100));
    }
    printf("=========================================\n");

    // Variables for the race
    int pilotes_numbers[MAX_PILOTES]  = {44, 6, 5, 7, 3, 33, 19, 77, 11, 27, 26, 55, 14, 22, 9, 12, 20, 30, 8, 21, 31, 94}; // Tab containing pilotes numbers
    struct Pilote Q2[16]; // Tab of pilotes for Q2
    struct Pilote Q3[10]; // Tab of pilotes for Q3
    struct Pilote mainRun[MAX_PILOTES]; // Tab of pilotes for other race, practices
    struct Pilote *pilotesTab; // pointer to SM
    pid_t tabPID[MAX_PILOTES]; // Tab of PID
    int shmid = 0; // SM id
    key_t key; // Key for SM and Semaphores

     /**
     * Shared memory
     */

    // Key generation for Shared Memory
    key = ftok(argv[0], 123); // argv[O] => name of the program launched, ID (char)

    // SM initialization
    shmid = shmget(key, MAX_PILOTES * sizeof(Pilote), IPC_CREAT | 0644); 

    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("Erreur when allocating SM.");
        return 0;
    }

    // Attach SM segment
    pilotesTab = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    /**
     * Semaphores
     */

    // Semaphores initialization (1 semaphore)
    semid = semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0640); // key, number of semaphores, perm 

    if(semid == -1) { // Erreur
        perror("Error when creating semaphore");
        return 0;
    }

    // Set semaphore value to 1
    int rv = semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, 1); // semid, sem number, operation type, union semun 

    if (rv == -1) { // sif return value == -1
        perror("Error when affecting value to the semaphore");
        return 0;
    }



    /**
     * Fork
     */

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < MAX_PILOTES; j++) { /* Create 22 processes */

        tabPID[j] = fork();

        if (tabPID[j] == -1) { // Error
            perror("Error when forking\n");
            return 0;
        }

       if (tabPID[j] == 0) { // Child
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623131/why-is-rand-not-so-random-after-fork
            srand(time(NULL) ^ (getpid() << 16));
            pilotesTab[j].pilote_id = pilotes_numbers[j]; // Pilote number initialization
            run(&pilotesTab[j], "Practices");

            exit(0);
        } 
    } /* End of 22 processes */

    printf("==================================================== \n");
    fillTab(mainRun, pilotesTab, 0, MAX_PILOTES); // Fill the tab before sorting + show to the console
    showResults(mainRun, MAX_PILOTES, "Practices");
    printf("====================================================\n");

    /**
     * END TEST
     */
    semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID); // Semaphore remove
    shmdt(pilotesTab); // SM detach
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0); // SM remove
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the code that show the output in the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include "CourseF1.h"
#include "ResultCourse.h"

#define MAX_PILOTES 22

void showResults(struct Pilote tab[], int nbElems, char* name) {

    if (strcmp(name, "Race") != 0) { // NOT in Race
        qsort(tab, nbElems, sizeof(Pilote), compareBest);

        for (int k = 0; k < nbElems; k++) {

            // If the pilote gave up during session
            // But did a time
            if (tab[k].hasGivenUp) {
                printf(
                    "%d) voiture n°%d : Best S1 => %ds%dms | Best S2 => %ds%dms | Best S3 => %ds%dms | Best Lap => %dm%ds%dms || DNF\n", 
                    k+1,
                    tab[k].pilote_id, 
                    (tab[k].bestS1/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS1-(tab[k].bestS1/1000)*1000,
                    (tab[k].bestS2/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS2-(tab[k].bestS2/1000)*1000,
                    (tab[k].bestS3/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS3-(tab[k].bestS3/1000)*1000,
                    tab[k].best/60000, (tab[k].best/1000)%60, tab[k].best-(tab[k].best/1000)*1000
                );
                continue; 
            }

            // If the pilote gave up during first lap
            // HACK TIME to place it at the end of the list
            if (tab[k].hasGivenUp && tab[k].best == (3 * 60 * 3600) + 1) {
                printf("%d) voiture n°%d : // Abandon durant le premier tour de la session => Pas de temps // \n",
                    k+1,
                    tab[k].pilote_id
                );
                continue;
            }

            // If everything is OK
            printf(
                "%d) voiture n°%d : Best S1 => %ds%dms | Best S2 => %ds%dms | Best S3 => %ds%dms | Best Lap => %dm%ds%dms \n", 
                k+1,
                tab[k].pilote_id, 
                (tab[k].bestS1/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS1-(tab[k].bestS1/1000)*1000,
                (tab[k].bestS2/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS2-(tab[k].bestS2/1000)*1000,
                (tab[k].bestS3/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS3-(tab[k].bestS3/1000)*1000,
                tab[k].best/60000, (tab[k].best/1000)%60, tab[k].best-(tab[k].best/1000)*1000
            ); 
        }

    } else { // IN race
        for (int k = 0; k < nbElems; k++) {
            qsort(tab, nbElems, sizeof(Pilote), compareTot);

            if (tab[k].hasGivenUpDuringRace) {
                printf("%d) voiture n°%d: DNF (n'a pas pu finir l'entiereté de la course pour cause d'abandon)\n",
                    k+1,
                    tab[k].pilote_id
                );
                continue;
            } 

            printf(
                "%d) voiture n°%d : Best S1 => %ds%dms | Best S2 => %ds%dms | Best S3 => %ds%dms | Best Lap => %dm%ds%dms || Total => %dm%ds%dms \n", 
                k+1,
                tab[k].pilote_id, 
                (tab[k].bestS1/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS1-(tab[k].bestS1/1000)*1000,
                (tab[k].bestS2/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS2-(tab[k].bestS2/1000)*1000,
                (tab[k].bestS3/1000)%60, tab[k].bestS3-(tab[k].bestS3/1000)*1000,
                tab[k].best/60000, (tab[k].best/1000)%60, tab[k].best-(tab[k].best/1000)*1000,
                tab[k].totalTime/60000, (tab[k].totalTime/1000)%60, tab[k].totalTime-(tab[k].totalTime/1000)*1000
            ); 
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the buggy output in console:

```
1: voiture n°44: (0m0s0ms)
2: voiture n°6: (0m0s0ms)
3: voiture n°5: (0m0s0ms)
4: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
5: voiture n°3: (0m0s0ms)
6: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
7: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
8: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
9: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
10: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
11: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
12: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
13: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
14: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
15: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
16: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
17: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
18: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
19: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
20: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
21: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
22: voiture n°0: (0m0s0ms)
```

Hope that it's clear enough and that you will be able to help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using System V semaphores, which is ... quaint.  SysV semaphores have a couple of features that POSIX semaphores do not have, but I find the POSIX semaphore API considerably easier to use.  (On the other hand, I kinda like the SysV style for shared-memory segments, even though it, too, has a few quirks.)

As long as you're using SysV semaphores, you really ought to pay more attention to the docs for `semctl()`.  In particular:

> The fourth argument is optional and depends upon the operation
>   requested. If required, it is of type `union semun`, which the
>   application shall explicitly declare:
>
> ```
> union semun {
>     int val;
>     struct semid_ds *buf;
>     unsigned short  *array;
> } arg;
> ```

([POSIX specification for `semctl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html))

When you use the four-arg form to try to set the initial value of your semaphore, you pass a plain `int`.  That *might* appear to work, but it's non-conforming, so the behavior is undefined.

Additionally, since you intend for your shared-memory segment and semaphore to be inherited by child processes across the `fork()`s, as opposed to being opened independently, I recommend using key `IPC_PRIVATE` for each instead of specifying an application-specific key, though that won't be related to the misbehavior you observe.

But I think **the main problem you face here is that you do nothing to ensure that the child processes complete their work before the main process examines the results**.  The easiest and most natural way to achieve that in this case would be for the main program, after forking *all* the children, to `wait()` or `waitpid()` for each of them.

As a bonus, you should then be able to get rid of the semaphore altogether, for although the child processes all access the same shared memory segment, no two access the same part of it.  Therefore, they do not need to synchronize with respect to each other.  The successful waits will be sufficient to ensure that the parent properly synchronizes with all the children.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do that.