# How to get random number in forked processes?

Tags: perl, random, fork, random-seed

I'm forking few processes and I need each process to perform a task on a randomly selected items. 
I found that the forked processes pick the exact same random numbers. 
I tried generating seeds and call srand(), but it didn't help much. Actually, most documentation I've read suggest to avoid srand() "unless you know exactly what you're doing".

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
use MongoDB;
#use Math::Random::Secure qw(rand);

my $num_clients = shift;
my $num_loops = 50_000_000;

sub test_forked_sub {
    my $sum=0;
    my $random_offset = rand(120);
    printf "time: %10.4f -  Random offset: %6.2f at pid: %s  \n", time(), $random_offset, $$;
    for (my $i=0; $i < $num_loops  ; $i++) {
        $sum += rand(120);
    }
}

my $nub_processes = 0;
for (my $client_id =0; $client_id < $num_clients; $client_id++ ) {
    if (my $pid = fork) {     #Parent
        $nub_processes++;
    }
    else {         # child
        die "cannot fork: $!" unless defined $pid;
        test_forked_sub();
        exit(0);
    }
}

while ($nub_processes){
    wait;
    $nub_processes--;
}
```

When I run it I get the exact same "random" number in each of the processes:

```
$ time ./test_rand_fork.pl 10
time: 1569510011.6891 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2091
time: 1569510011.6937 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2092
time: 1569510011.6987 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2093
time: 1569510011.7028 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2094
time: 1569510011.7070 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2095
time: 1569510011.7097 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2096
time: 1569510011.7144 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2097
time: 1569510011.7203 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2098
time: 1569510011.7230 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2099
time: 1569510011.7249 -  Random offset:  46.64 at pid: 2100

real    0m3.974s
user    0m32.955s
sys     0m1.444s
```

A possible but ugly solution, it not to fork. Instead, to run multiple instances from my shell as follows:

```
# shell processes
$ for i in `seq 1 10`; do  ./test_rand_fork.pl 1 &  done
time: 1569511908.7708 -  Random offset:   7.44 at pid: 4129
time: 1569511908.8070 -  Random offset:  19.50 at pid: 4131
time: 1569511908.8068 -  Random offset:  97.59 at pid: 4132
time: 1569511908.8073 -  Random offset:  14.51 at pid: 4133
time: 1569511908.8077 -  Random offset:  16.70 at pid: 4134
time: 1569511908.8080 -  Random offset: 108.63 at pid: 4138
time: 1569511908.8079 -  Random offset:  69.44 at pid: 4137
time: 1569511908.8080 -  Random offset:  83.25 at pid: 4136
time: 1569511908.8080 -  Random offset:  43.33 at pid: 4135
time: 1569511908.8203 -  Random offset:  33.82 at pid: 4139
```

As the "shell processes" is an ugly solution, I tried to use Math::Random::Secure. 
Here are the results I get randomness as needed but it is 50 times slower than the "shell processes" approach:

```
# using: Math::Random::Secure qw(rand);
$ time ./test_rand_fork.pl 10
time: 1569510036.9331 -  Random offset: 112.48 at pid: 2128
time: 1569510036.9470 -  Random offset:  47.15 at pid: 2129
time: 1569510036.9501 -  Random offset:  20.77 at pid: 2130
time: 1569510036.9517 -  Random offset:  40.98 at pid: 2131
time: 1569510036.9521 -  Random offset:  13.84 at pid: 2132
time: 1569510036.9538 -  Random offset:  20.43 at pid: 2133
time: 1569510036.9543 -  Random offset:  48.48 at pid: 2134
time: 1569510036.9563 -  Random offset: 109.29 at pid: 2135
time: 1569510036.9579 -  Random offset:  70.30 at pid: 2136
time: 1569510036.9601 -  Random offset:  24.31 at pid: 2137

real    3m17.251s
user    32m31.129s
sys     0m1.054s
```

The randomness I need is not for security purposes, I just need a good spread. 
Is there a way to generate a good-enough seed for the forked processes and still use the standard rand() or alternative faster way? or at least something that doesn't require installing additional library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is rand() not so random after fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623131/why-is-rand-not-so-random-after-fork)

Comment: @PeterO. Um, no -- that discusses a different use case. Of course that one can use `rand` across `fork`s, that's one of (very few) purposes of `srand` (when used accordingly).  See an example in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed [srand](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html) that you want. While it is true that generally one need not muck about with it, there are a few uses

> However, there are a few situations where programs are likely to want to call `srand`. One is for generating predictable results, generally for testing or debugging. There, you use `srand($seed)`, with the same `$seed` each time.

and, precisely for your purpose

> Another case is that you may want to call `srand` after a `fork` to avoid child processes sharing the same seed value as the parent (and consequently each other).

A quicky example

```
perl -wE'
    say "Parent $$ rand: ", rand;  
    for (1..4) { 
        $pid = fork // die "Cant fork: $!"; 
        if ($pid == 0) { srand(); say "\tchild $$ rand: ", rand; exit } 
    }'
```

Prints

```
Parent 23375 rand: 0.502774688721733
        child 23376 rand: 0.914527430039929
        child 23377 rand: 0.97985713889739
        child 23378 rand: 0.127702740327553
        child 23379 rand: 0.187181734786467
```

It is the `srand` up there that does the trick; without it the numbers are the same (as they must be).  Note that it can be run with a seed as well, which gives us better diagnostic/testing control.

---

A note, to avoid spreading bad habits.

In a quick program as above the child processes get cleaned up by the system (reaped by *init*). However, one really should *always* reap so the above should really have

```
for (1..4) { 
    $pid = fork // die "Cant fork: $!"; 
    if ($pid == 0) { srand(); say "\tchild $$ rand: ", rand; exit } 
    push @procs, $pid;
}
for (@procs) { $gone = wait; say "$gone exited with $?" }
```

just better with [waitpid](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html) and non-blocking for better monitoring, and perhaps in a [signal handler](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals).

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding:
`srand()`
just before calling rand. Still got the exact same randoms.

Comment: @Yuval Yes, you mention -- I don't know what went wrong there?

Comment: I looked again, I had a typo and didn't call `srand()` as I thought. 
So why actually people use the random libraries for general purposes that are not security instead of simply using `srand` ?

Comment: @Yuval  "_why actually people use ... instead of simply using srand_"  -- I don't know. A good use of `rand` is exactly what you say in your good question, when "_just need a good spread_". Using seed (`srand` for `rand`) can be useful (for specific purposes), in any language, environment, or library.